# Asp.Net Windows Authentication with Long Usersnames

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am having this strange problem with Windows Authentication in ASP.NET.

A user complaints that he cannot use his username to access one of my systems. However, the username is correct and every other user is able to access it.

When I tried to use my C# code to query the Active Directory to look for that user, I get an error that the user is not there! But, he is.

when I sent this to our technical team, they said that it is because the username is "too long" and then they gave me another one. which worked.

how can a user have an active username on AD and still cannot use it to login to ASP.NET web app

any idea?

Comment: What is the username? What is the error or exception you get when you want to login with that user?

Comment: well, the username exceeds 25 chars .. and the exception i am getting when i am querying the AD is NULL exception, which means that it could not find the user